# How can i publish polygon layer on Geoserver with polygon geometry

Tags: geoserver, shapefile

I can not publish polygon layer (ESRI Shapefile) on Geoserver with Polygon geometry.

Every time is published as MultiPolygon. Shapefile has really Polygon geometry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shapefiles don't distinguish between polygons and multipolygons so GeoServer always promotes treats them as MultiPolygons for safety. This shouldn't cause you any issues later.

Comment: I agree that usually MultiPolygons are safer. However, if you really need polygons you can read http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/services/wfs/schemamapping.html#schema-customization and change the "gml:MultiPolygonPropertyType" into "gml:PolygonPropertyType" in schema.xsd.